# Missing something when using custom CRS to define projection for NOAA QPF

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to display NOAA QPF data and this: https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6770/
suggests the proj string should be:

Proj4: `+proj=longlat +a=6371200 +b=6371200 +no_defs`

which matches:
https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/html/mapprojection.txt

GEOGCS["GCS_Sphere_EMEP",
DATUM["D_Sphere_EMEP",
SPHEROID["Sphere_EMEP",6371200.0,0.0]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

However, I get this as output:
[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My overall goal is to ingest the WFS from here: https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/NWS_Forecasts_Guidance_Warnings/wpc_qpf/MapServer/WFSServer  into QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had to change the proj4 definition to:

```
+proj=longlat +R=6371008.7714 +no_defs
```

which seemed to work - though not sure if that is the proper way to do this.